# Issue while trying to post / get an API on expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to react-native and it's my first app.

I'm trying to develop my app and connect it to my API. I develop all my app with the navigator view on Expo and there is no problem, the connection is good and I can get or post everything.

Now that I'm trying to fetch it with expo on my Android or Apple, there is no response.

Here is my code for the authentication:

login.js

```
import { post } from '../request/post';

export const login = (mail, pass) => {
  console.log(mail)
  console.log(pass)
  console.log("POST request for login");
    return post('/api/login', {
        email: mail,
        password: pass,
        mobile: true
    });
};
```

post.js

```
import { API_URL } from '../url';
import { getStorageToken } from '../../utils/asyncStorage';

const getHeaders = async () => {
  const token = await getStorageToken();
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  if (token !== 'undefined' && token.length > 0) {
    headers['auth'] = `${token}`;
  }

  return headers;
};

export const post = async (destination, body) => {
  const headers = await getHeaders();

  const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}${destination}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });

  console.log(result);

  if (result.ok) {
    return await result.json();
  }
  throw { error: result.status };
};
```

loginPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet,  ScrollView, Image, TextInput, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { setStorageAfterConnection } from '../../utils/asyncStorage';
import { CheckBox, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { login } from '../../api/auth/login';


export default class LogIn extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: ''
         };
  }

  submit = () => {
    login(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(async (res) => {
        await setStorageAfterConnection(res);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        if (res && res.error) {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: res.error});
        }
        this.setState({ errorMessage: "Erreur de connexion"});
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
            ...............................................
              );
            }
}
```

I tried to debug it and it seems to not find the function post() because I don't have any network request. I do not know what's the correct way to do an "API" component so I think I probably made some mistakes but I didn't find what I'm missing.

I used Lan connection and my API isn't hosted on local.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add async-await to "login":

```
export const login = async (mail, pass) => {  <---- 'async' ADDED
  console.log(mail)
  console.log(pass)
  console.log("POST request for login");
    return await post('/api/login', {  <---- 'await' ADDED
        email: mail,
        password: pass,
        mobile: true
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put some debug on my code:

```
export const post = async (destination, body) => {
  console.log("A");
  const headers = await getHeaders();
  console.log("B")

  const result = await fetch(`${API_URL}${destination}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });

  console.log(result);

  if (result.ok) {
    return await result.json();
  }
  throw { error: result.status };
};
```

And I get on the console:

email

password

POST request for login

A

So the problem seems to be on my await getHeaders()

EDIT: Problem was solved. It was because of the getHeaders that try to get the token and failed.